How to setup external load balancing to my kubernetes cluster securely?
We have for a period of time just pointed our dns to one of the nodes in our cluster. That node has then load balanced internally to the correct node and application.
Something like this:

The problem has been that sometimes the node has crashed, so much that we can't even ssh into it.
And since the dns points to that node all applications stop being accessible.
So my though was to setup an external load balancer and point the dns to this.
Something like this:

I have tried using HAProxy with good results.
It seems to work fine.
But I am only using http between the load balancer and the k8s cluster.
I would like that traffic to be secured as well.
How can I make that happen?
The k8s distribution atm is k3s.

I think there are two methods on how to do this [1]:

HAProxy SSL Passthrough SSL Passthrough does what it says, it takes
the connection and throws it to a backend server to decrypt. This
could be considered faster but has many drawbacks like hiding the
client’s true IP. That’s because we don’t decrypt the data as it
passes through the load balancer.
HAProxy SSL Termination With SSL Termination, HAProxy decrypts the
connection as it hits the load balancer and then either encrypts it
again to send on to a backend server or just sends the data in an
unencrypted fashion. This is considered the default choice but it
depends on how you are using HAProxy with HTTPS connections.

There's a more detailed guide here:

Set up HAProxy HTTPS – Load balance Over HTTPS Connections

Load Balancer with HAProxy SSL Termination


[1]. https://first2host.co.uk/blog/set-up-haproxy-https-load-balance-over-https-connections/

Thanks I will try this out asap
